# TKT_ElectronicDocumentServicesRQ SOAP API for SABRE is not responding from java code, getting http.USG_SVC_PROVIDER_FAILURE Error

Tags: web-services, soap, sabre

When calling the TKT_ElectronicDocumentServicesRQ API through Java, I get the following error (see in detail in the response), although the same request works fine with SOAP UI and Postman.

```
com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationException: errors.http.USG_SVC_PROVIDER_FAILURE
```

** Changed the original value of PCC, URL and DocumentType in this post

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tns:Envelope xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><tns:Header><mes:MessageHeader xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader"><mes:From><mes:PartyId>app.com</mes:PartyId></mes:From><mes:To><mes:PartyId>sabre.com</mes:PartyId></mes:To><mes:CPAId>ABCD</mes:CPAId><mes:ConversationId>webservices.support@sabre.com</mes:ConversationId><mes:Service mes:type="OTA">TKT_ElectronicDocumentServicesRQ</mes:Service><mes:Action>TKT_ElectronicDocumentServicesRQ</mes:Action><mes:MessageData><mes:MessageId>5</mes:MessageId><mes:Timestamp>Mon Jun 05 10:57:28 IST 2023</mes:Timestamp></mes:MessageData></mes:MessageHeader><sec:Security xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><sec:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESB!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!1685942995424!7248!261!1</sec:BinarySecurityToken></sec:Security></tns:Header><tns:Body><GetElectronicDocumentRQ xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/ns/Ticketing/EDoc" Version="2.2.0"><STL:STL_Header.RQ xmlns:STL="http://www.sabre.com/ns/Ticketing/EDocStl"/><STL:POS xmlns:STL="http://www.sabre.com/ns/Ticketing/EDocStl"/><SearchParameters><DocumentNumber>9517965098917</DocumentNumber><DocumentType>TKT</DocumentType></SearchParameters></GetElectronicDocumentRQ></tns:Body></tns:Envelope>
```

**Response**

<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap-env:Header<eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"><eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">sabre.com</eb:PartyId></eb:From><eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">app.com</eb:PartyId></eb:To><eb:CPAId>ABCD</eb:CPAId><eb:ConversationId>webservices.support@sabre.com</eb:ConversationId><eb:Service eb:type="OTA">TKT_ElectronicDocumentServicesRQ</eb:Service><eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action><eb:MessageData><eb:MessageId>3078379332886332320</eb:MessageId><eb:Timestamp>2023-06-05T09:14:48</eb:Timestamp><eb:RefToMessageId>8</eb:RefToMessageId></eb:MessageData></eb:MessageHeader><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess/SessMgr:1.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS/RESF!ICESMSLB/RES.LB!1685955612572!9942!297!1</wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header>soap-env:Bodysoap-env:Faultsoap-env:Server.SystemFailureService provider invocation failed. (Possibly service provider server down)com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationException: errors.http.USG_SVC_PROVIDER_FAILURE</soap-env:Fault></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>

Kindly Help me to understand the problem